# Float left and right on same line without the container getting resized

Tags: css, alignment

I need to align two inline block elements; one to the left and the other to the right side of a card container

Below is my code

```css
    .list {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .card {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 10px auto;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        padding: 10px;
        border-left: 3px solid #cb202d;
    }

    .button {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 6px;
        margin: 8px;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #cb202d;

    }

    .button:hover {
        background: #D94148;
        ;
    }

    .namebox {
        padding: 6px;
        margin: 8px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
        <button class="button">Button Text</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to align the buttons to the right side of the card

I tried adding `float:right` to the button, however it shrinks the card container and the button goes out of the card.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on card element and set `justify-content: space-between`. Or you can use `margin-left: auto` on button element. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g2ych6s3/2/)

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #cb202d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #cb202d;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #D94148;
}
.namebox {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <span class="namebox">Span Sample Text</span>
    <button class="button">Button Text</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```